# Getting Errors on android application on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

```
[2016-02-23 14:52:23 - Driver] E:\android_workspace\Driver\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:23 - Driver] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:23 - Driver] E:\android_workspace\Driver\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:23 - Driver] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:23 - Driver] E:\android_workspace\Driver\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:23 - Driver] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:24 - Driver] E:\android_workspace\Driver\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:24 - Driver] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:24 - Driver] E:\android_workspace\Driver\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:24 - Driver] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:24 - Driver] E:\android_workspace\Driver\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:24 - Driver] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:25 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:25 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:25 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:25 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:26 - google-play-services_lib] C:\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v11\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:26 - google-play-services_lib] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:26 - google-play-services_lib] C:\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:26 - google-play-services_lib] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:41 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:41 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:41 - android-support-v7-appcompat] C:\Android\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:41 - android-support-v7-appcompat] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:42 - google-play-services_lib] C:\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v11\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:42 - google-play-services_lib] 
[2016-02-23 14:52:42 - google-play-services_lib] C:\Android\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
[2016-02-23 14:52:42 - google-play-services_lib]
```

Comment: Please post your manifest file also

Comment: did you include appcompat to your project?

Comment: Yes I import app compat library

Comment: @Vishnu here is manifest file http://expirebox.com/download/23c9fdc98f9d192ab0067a24848a7ccd.html

Answer (score 1):

### Automatically created project "appcompat_v7" in eclipse might cause this error

I used to solve this kind of errors by following 2 steps :
1.delete the **“appcompat_v7”** project
2.make necessary changes in all the **style.xml** files, **main.xml** and **main_actvity.java** required due to deletion of “appcompat_v7”  project

Necessary Changes :

1. In **main_actvity.java** extend **Activity** & remove  which is extended by default. Remove all other code inside the main_activity class apart from that OnCreate method.
2. In all the the style.xml inside the style tag change the value of parent.

   you will find 
   **"parent=Theme.AppCompat.Light" or "parent=anyother thing"**
   make it
   **"parent=@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"**
   even you can use any other value for parent.I just gave a random theme.
3. do the same thing in main.xml like above.

and finally clean the project before you run.